# Find zeros (many decimals) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, find

I have a vector which contains values such as: [-0.0081 -0.0060 -0.0020 -0.0014 -0.0002 0.0002 0.0005 0.0004 0.0003 0.0001 0.0001 0.0000 -0.0000 -0.0001 -0.0000 0.0000]', and I want to find the places where the number is zero (the values which seem to be zeros if the numbers are displayed with four decimals). In this case I mean that my result should be a vector which contains these rows: [12 13 15 16].

I tried with "find" function which works with integers and bigger decimal numbers, but not with these numbers so I'm a bit confused now...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need. Assume your vector is called `a`:

```
find(abs(a) < 0.00005)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for both replies! It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find(abs(matrix1) < THRESHOLD)
```

where "THRESHOLD" is whatever value you want it to be - in this case it's 0.0001.

Comment: I think the threshold needs to be 0.00005, because of the rounding for display.